# Can "Run Keyword If" not be run under the keyword section of Robotframework code

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to execute this peace of Robot framework code.
I always get an error on the
"Run Keyword" If statement
error message: No keyword with name 'Run Keyword If '${checkmessageoutput}' == 'Expected aircraft ID, i.e. MLH001'' found.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Is it not possible to use

```
*** Settings ***

Documentation     A Test of the TAS-APP-FDD-3
...               Kari Dec 2014

Suite Setup       fdd attach to application

Library           BuiltIn
Library           fddlibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Send a valid flight plan
    [Template]  send a flightplan
    FI352   \

Fill out a flight plan missing callsign
    [Template]  send a flightplan
    /   Expected aircraft ID, i.e. MLH001  

*** Keyword ***
fill out flight plan
     fdd select msg
     fdd msg select fpl
     fdd msg fpl priority                  FF
     fdd msg fpl ssr                       1234
     fdd msg fpl flightrules               I
     fdd msg fpl flighttype                S
     #fdd msg fpl callsign                  FI351
     fdd msg fpl aircrafttype              A310
     fdd msg fpl wakecategory              H
     fdd msg fpl equipmentcommnav          SHIR
     fdd msg fpl equipmentsurveillance     S
     fdd msg fpl departureairport          BIKF
     fdd msg fpl departuretime             0800
     fdd msg fpl crusingspeed              M080
     fdd msg fpl cruisinglevel             F300
     fdd msg fpl route                     ALDAN RATSO
     fdd msg fpl destinationairport        EKCH
     fdd msg fpl eet                       0300
     fdd msg fpl otherinformation          Flightplan 1

send a flightplan
    [arguments]     ${callsign}     ${checkmessageoutput}  
    fill out flight plan
    fdd msg fpl callsign              ${callsign}
    check flight plan                 ${checkmessageoutput}
    Run Keyword If '${checkmessageoutput}' == 'Expected aircraft ID, i.e. MLH001'     log to console     \nRun send flight plan
    ELSE  log to console     \nRun send no flight plan      

check flight plan
    [arguments]                     ${checkmessageoutput} 
    fdd msg fpl check message
    ${message}=     fdd msg fpl return message
    Should be equal     ${message}  ${checkmessageoutput}       

send flight plan
    fdd msg fpl send message

display strip     
    fdd select flights
    fdd flights display electronic strip
```

Comment: Library           BuiltIn in Settings is unnecessary as it's imported automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a close look at the error message:

```
No keyword with name 'Run Keyword If '${checkmessageoutput}' == 'Expected aircraft ID, i.e. MLH001'' found.
```

Notice it's *not* saying there's no keyword named `Run Keyword If`, but rather `Run Keyword If '${check...`. In other words, you're missing a separator between the keyword and its arguments so it thinks that whole sentence is a single keyword. Add another space or tab or whatever you're using after `Run Keyword If`.

These sorts of errors are why I recommend using the pipe-separated format -- this type of error almost never happens, and it is much easier to diagnose.